# How can I get the chainable subject when overriding the Cypress clear() command?

Tags: cypress

Cypress' documentation shows [overwriting the `type` command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Overwrite-type-command) as an example. I assumed overwriting [`clear`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clear) should be very similar:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('clear', (_originalFn, element, options) => {
  element.type('{selectall}{backspace}', options);
});
```

However, IDEA tells me the type of `element` is `Partial<ClearOptions>`, so it seems to be the options parameter. And when running, I get

```
element.type is not a function
```

How can I get the actual element to call `type` on?

(I know the documentation says `clear` is already an alias of `type('{selectall}{backspace}')`; somehow in the project I am working on, after upgrading to Cypress 12 a test fails with `clear` and passes with `type('{selectall}{backspace}')`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexy Romanov's answer is close, but not quite what is needed.

- Why does the IDE think that `element` is of type `Partial<ClearOptions>`?
- Answer: Your IDE is defaulting to thinking that your override is using `Cypress.CommandFnWithOriginalFnAndSubject<'clear'>`, which only has `originalFn` and `options` as parameters, with `options` having the type of `Partial<ClearOptions> | undefined`. If you are able to type `originalFn` as `CommandFnWithOriginalFn<'clear'>`, your IDE should be able to interpret that a `prevSubject` (unfortunately typed as `unknown`) parameter is required.

But, and this is unclear from the `type` example, as that is using the original `cy.type()` command, you'll need to wrap the yielded `prevSubject` object for Cypress to be able to use it in your chain.

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite(
  'clear',
  (
    _originalFn: Cypress.CommandFnWithOriginalFn<'clear'>,
    element: unknown,
    _options: Partial<Cypress.ClearOptions> | undefined
  ) => {
    return cy.wrap(element).type('{selectall}{backspace}');
  }
);
```

You can see that I am using `cy.wrap()` instead of `cy.get()`, because the element yielded is of type `Cypress.Chainable<Element>` (or maybe a more specific type than `Element`), which does not have `.type()` as a property, nor is it an appropriate type for use with `cy.get()`.

If you are not using TypeScript and cannot type the parameters, it *should* still work, but typing the parameters will make the IDE recognize the signature.

You can also see that I am omitting using the `options` parameter at all, as `cy.clear()`'s options are `Partial<Cypress.ClearOptions>`, and `cy.type()`'s options are `Partial<Cypress.TypeOptions>`, and providing options to your custom `cy.clear()` may (and probably will) result in mismatching options parameter used by `cy.type()`.

In addition to all of this, it may just be worth the time to add a new custom command that does this action, as using `Cypress.Commands.overwrite` can cause unforeseen issues - I personally do not use `overwrite` at all for that reason.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'myClear',
  { prevSubject: 'element' },
  (
    subject: Cypress.Chainable<Element>,
    options: Partial<Cypress.TypeOptions>
  ) => {
    return cy.wrap(subject).type('{selectall}{backspace}', options);
  }
);
```

Comment: He is specifically talking about [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). There seems to be no problem with VSCode - if you hover over the custom command, it shows `+1 overload` which means it has picked up both type definitions.

Comment: "may (and probably will) result in mismatching options parameter used by cy.type()." I understand. But most options are in `Loggable, Timeoutable, ActionableOptions` which both extend.

Comment: And thanks on being correct on `wrap`!

Answer (score 0):

The type declaration (or inference?) is wrong;

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('clear', (_originalFn, element, options) => {
  cy.get(element).type('{selectall}{backspace}', options);
});
```

works.

Comment: Only in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I should have checked VS Code too. Oh well.